# Calculated YTD using date column and group by multiple column?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, zoho

I have a table with columns:
[image]

I'm trying to calculate accounts payable in days `= (Accounts Payable/YTD_Vendor_Expenses)*Number of days in Period`.

I'm trying the below query but doesn't seem to work(I'm running the query in ZOHO analytics):

```
SELECT groupkey,
`Total Accounts Payable`,
Report_Month,
`Total Income`,
month(`Report_Month`) * 30 as `Number of Days in Period`,
YTD(sum(`Vendor Expenses`),`Report_Month`) as `YTD_Vendor Expenses`,
(sum(`Total Accounts Payable`) / YTD(sum("Vendor Expenses"),"Report_Month") * (month(`Report_Month`) * 30) 
FROM  apd_table  
GROUP BY `groupkey`,
`Report_Month`,
`Total Accounts Payable`,
`Total Income`
```

I'm looking for output like below:
[image]

Please help me with this. Thank you.